# Longitudinal displacement for a non-homogeneous bar

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, continuum-mechanics

Could you help me understand homogeneous definition got myself in a pickle regarding non-homogeneous. Derivation of a partial differential equation modelling longitudinal displacement $u(x,t)$ due to tension and compression.

Comment: Is your question about homogeneous or non-homogeneous properties of a bar under compression? Also what steps have you taken and where is the difficulty you have. There are plenty of online resources explaining how to derive the equations based on a balance of forces and your post might be closed unless you show what _specifically_ you are having trouble with.

Comment: Need to derive a partial differential equation modelling longitudinal displacement for a non homogeneous bar

Comment: Lots of resources defining equations for homogeneous bar but can't find anything for a bar with varying density and Young's modulus along its length.

Comment: The diff. equation is valid at every point regardless if homogeneity provided the correct speed of sound $c = \sqrt{E/\rho}$ constant is used at every $x$ value. Only to solve the equation the assumption of homogeneity is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the basic equations if the cross-sectional area, $A$, of the bar is uniform across its entire length.

Newton's second law:
$$\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x} + \frac{p}{A}=\rho \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}$$

where $p$ is an axial distributed load per unit length, $\sigma$ is the stress in the bar, $\rho$ is the density, and $u$ is the longitudinal displacement.

Hooke's law: $$\sigma=E \epsilon$$

where $E$ is the Young's modulus and $\epsilon$ is the strain. Note that both $E$ and $\rho$ can depend on the position $x$ along the bar.

Kinematics: $$\epsilon=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

Now, combining these three components we have: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(E\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{p}{A}=\rho \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}$$